# Is it possible to query 2 explicit pro*c connections in the same query?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I created 2 explicit connections to the same database can I build a query that will use both connections in a union so that each query runs concurrently?

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :uName1 IDENTIFIED BY :passwd1 AT :DB_NAME1 USING :dbString1
EXEC SQL CONNECT :uName2 IDENTIFIED BY :passwd2 AT :DB_NAME2 USING :dbString1

EXEC SQL at :DB_NAME1 SELECT .....
UNION
EXEC SQL at :DB_NAME2 SELECT .....
```